# Writing to a file in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to write to a file in a Asp.Net form (.aspx).  I can create the file fine using,

```
  if (!File.Exists(Settings.Default.FileLocation))
     {
       File.Create(Settings.Default.FileLocation);
     }
```

But when I go to write to the file using this code:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Settings.Default.FileLocation, someByteArray);
```

I get an exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com\captured\captured.xml' because it is being used by another process.
```

(in this case 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.com\captured\captured.xml' == Settings.Default.FileLocation)

I cant delete or copy the file in Windows Explorer during this time as well.  However, if I stop or restart the Application Pool the WebForm is running in, the error goes away.  What is the cause of this and how do I prevent it?

This is running on a Win server 2012 R2 and IIS 7.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx). You should be using `using` statements to open the file so that you can make sure any open handles to it are closed.

```
using(FileStream fs=File.Create(Settings.Default.FileLocation))
{
    //manipulate file here
}
```

Also, `File.WriteAllBytes` [will create the file if it doesn't exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), so there's no need to separately create it.

Comment: Yeah I figured this out right after I put up the question.  Facepalm moment

Comment: @Mike_G The real lesson here is "Check MSDN when confused about stuff built into .NET". Being confused about how `File.Create()` works is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

[File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) opens the file for read/write by default and needs to be closed before it can be used again.  From the docs:

> By default, full read/write access to new files is granted to all
>   users. The file is opened with read/write access and must be closed
>   before it can be opened by another application.

[File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) will create the file if it doesn't exist, so I think your code to check for file existence and creating it is probably overkill.